# Calling Change on SELECT Dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdownlist which is declared like this:

```
<select class="ddl" onchange="reloadValues(this)">
options... 
</select>
```

There is another dropdownlist which is identical

```
<select class="ddl" onchange="reloadValues(this)">
options... 
</select>
```

When I change the first dropdownlist the reloadValues function is fired. How can I also fire the reloadValues of the second dropdownlist.

Comment: Instead of `(this)` use a selector to get the 2nd one in there.

Comment: There can be many many dropdownlist not only 2nd.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('ddl')` or jQuery `$('.ddl')`

Comment: Let's just say I cannot change the arguments for the reloadValues function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery, you can do it like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ddl").change(function(ev) {
        var that = this;
        reloadValues(that);
        $(".ddl").each(function(item, index) {
             if(this !== that)
                 reloadValues(this);
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jquery

```
function reloadValues(that)
{
    var ddl=document.getElementsByTagName('select')
    for(i=0;i<ddl.length;i++)
    {
        if(ddl[i].className=='ddl')
        {
            if(that==ddl[i])
            {
                alert("This element triggered the event and contains "+ddl[i].length+" items!");
            }
            else
            {    
               // Do something
               alert("This element didn't trigger the event and contains "+ddl[i].length+" items!");
            }
        }
    }        
}​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zg6XR/8/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot compare the actual functions as the onevent function is unique per element.

It would look something like

```
function onchange()
{
reloadValues(this)
}
```

It would be super elegant if we could loop through all selects and compare the `reloadValues` function inside the unique per element `onchange` function to see if it's the same function or not.

But a separate function would be assigned to each element, so they cannot be directly compared.  You could compare the string values by `element1.onchange+'' == element2.onchange+''` but you may get unexpected results in some browsers, as they will format the string value differently sometimes.

Here is an example that works by checking the string value of the attribute.  E.g. it performs the same routine on all elements that have the value `reloadValues(this)` set to their `onchange` attribute.

In this example, changing the index of one select changes any select on the page to the same index so long as it has the `reloadValues(this)` text exactly in its `onchange` attribute.  In this example, it doesn't matter what the `id` or `class` attributes are of the selects.

However, tagging or changing the text value of the `onchange` attribute will affect it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function reloadValues( XXX ) {  

    var allSelects = document.body.getElementsByTagName("select");

    for( var i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i++) {
        if(allSelects[i].attributes["onchange"].value == "reloadValues(this)") {
            allSelects[i].selectedIndex = XXX.options.selectedIndex;
        }
    }   

}


</script>


<body>

<select class="ddl" onchange="reloadValues(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="fsfsfs" onchange="reloadValues(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="ddl" onchange="reloadValues(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select class="ddl" onchange="reloadValues(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```